# Issues deleting from a React grandchild component

Tags: reactjs, typescript, event-handling, components, react-props

I am having issues using a handleDelete function that is passed down to a grandchild with all the necessary props.

The structure of my components can go either: Deck > CardSlider > Card or Deck > Card, depending on if the user is in grid or carousel view. When I call the handleDelete function from Deck -> Card component (grid view), I am able to successfully delete the card, however I can't delete when I go from Deck -> CardSlider -> Card in carousel view.

When I check the network in chrome devtools, it shows a 200 status code for DELETE, however it doesn't actually delete!

I'm completely stumped. Any ideas?

```js
async function handleDeleteCard(cardId: number) {
    const newDeck = await deleteCard(deckId, cardId)
    setCards(newDeck.cards);        
}

return (
       <div className="deck">
          
          {view == 'grid' ? 

            <ul className="cards">
              {cards.map((card, cardId) => 
                <li key={cardId}>
                    <Card 
                      card={card}
                      cardBack={cardBack} 
                      cardFront={cardFront}
                      cardId={cardId} 
                      flippedCard={flippedCard} 
                      handleDeleteCard={handleDeleteCard} 
                      handleFlip={handleFlip} 
                      mode={mode}
                      view={view}
                    />
                </li>)}
            </ul> 
            :
            <CardSlider 
              cards={cards}
              cardBack={cardBack} 
              cardFront={cardFront} 
              flippedCard={flippedCard}  
              handleFlip={handleFlip} 
              handleDeleteCard={handleDeleteCard} 
              mode={mode} 
              view={view}
            />
          }
)
```

[CardSlider component](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Y1Ko6.png)

[Card component](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ogc3F.png)

I tried passing the Card component all the necessary props from the CardSlider component in order to delete the card in caroussel view. I get the proper card ID and deck ID when I log the card details to be deleted in the handleDelete function, however it doesn't actually get deleted

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow, Donald! Unfortunately we won't be able to help much with this. Asking people to dive into a entire repository of code that includes backend and frontend interactions is a lot to ask. Please [edit] your question to include a [_minimal_ reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) that has the relevant code directly in your post. This should help you get an answer to your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is that you give `cardId` 2 different meanings:

- In `Deck` > `Card`, `cardId` is the [*index*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map#parameters) of the card within the `cards` array:

```
// cardId is the 2nd parameter of map callback,
// i.e. the index in the array being mapped
cards.map((card, cardId) =>
  <li key={cardId}>
    <Card 
      card={card}
      cardId={cardId} // Index
      handleDeleteCard={handleDeleteCard} 
      />
  </li>)
```

- In `Deck` > `CardSlider` > `Card`, it is now the `card._id` property (`ObjectId` or `string` from MongoDB document?)

```
<Card 
  card={cards[currentIndex]}
  cardId={cards[currentIndex]._id} // Document identifier, instead of index

  // handleDeleteCard={() => handleDeleteCard(cards[currentIndex]._id)}
/>
```

When you monitor the `DELETE` request, you should see the difference in `cardId` argument.

> When I call the handleDelete function from Deck -> Card component (grid view), I am able to successfully delete the card, however I can't delete when I go from Deck -> CardSlider -> Card in carousel view.

This means that your Backend knows only how to handle `cardId` as the card *index* within an array of cards, but not as the `card._id` field.

While an immediate solution could be to bring consistency in `cardId` meaning by changing what `CardSlider` uses (I suspect that it loops in the same order over the `cards` array, so it should be able to generate the same index, very probably already as `currentIndex`):

```
<Card 
  card={cards[currentIndex]}
  cardId={currentIndex} // Index, assuming it is in the same order as in cards array?

  handleDeleteCard={() => handleDeleteCard(currentIndex)}
/>
```

...a more robust solution would on the contrary change `Deck` and your Backend, so that they handle the actual `card._id` value (which is really a "cardId" and not just an "index").

That way, you would be able to delete any arbitrary card in a deck, even if the `cards` array is shuffled for example.

Comment: Thank you for pointing out that I was deleting with the index instead of an actual ID!